# Convert URI to String taking only host, port and path

Tags: java, string, uri

I have object of [`java.net.URI`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) type and I want to convert it to `String` representation, but I'm interested only in the following components:

- host
- port
- path

I don't want to have any other elements like query, fragment, user-info or scheme.

Doing it manually by `getHost()`, `getPort()` and `getPath()` looks like a fragile solution. Is there any `URI` formatter or customized `toString` available?

By fragile here I mean that there might be some corner-cases that I could forget to handle manually. Like e.g. the case when host is IPv6 address and then it [needs to have brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Literal_IPv6_addresses_in_network_resource_identifiers).

Comment: @SamSun I would need to do all the concatenation and handling missing components by hand which would be error prone

Comment: @MichalKordas: It seems reasonably simple to me, to be honest. About 10 lines of code, easily tested...

Comment: The URI standard is well documented. I would imagine a simple `String.format` should be more than enough.

Comment: @SamSun please see edited question, I still think there might be some corner cases that naive solution would not handle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could fairly easily build a new URI:

```
URI partial = new URI(
    null, // scheme
    null, // user info
    uri.getHost(),
    uri.getPort(),
    uri.getPath(),
    null, // query
    null); // fragment
String text = partial.toString();
```

You'd probably want to validate that the host is non-null in order for it to be sensible though.

Alternatively, the concatenation approach is really unlikely to be much more complicated - and I assume you'll have unit tests to check all combinations whatever the implementation.